# Naming constants on a boilerplate class

Tags: php, naming-conventions, constants

I'm creating a boilerplate class to use on every wordpress plugin i create . (Mods feel free to edit if "boilerplate" is not the correct way to call this). I have some constants that I use on all my plugins and all over the code, so i'm looking for the correct way to name them.

In my code i have this :

```
//edit these
define( 'WPB_PREFIX'                        , 'wsm');
define( 'WPB_SLUG'                          , 'wp-simple-monitor'); // Need to match plugin folder name
define( 'WPB_PLUGIN_NAME'                   , 'WP Simple Monitor');
define( 'WPB_VERSION'                       , '1.0');
//dont edit
define( WPB_PREFIX.'_ABS_PATH'              , WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/'. WPB_SLUG          );
define( WPB_PREFIX.'_REL_PATH'              , dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) )             );
define( WPB_PREFIX.'_PLUGIN_URL'            , WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/'. WPB_SLUG          );

class WP_Plugin_Base
    {
    // ...
    _e('Settings', WPB_PREFIX);
    // ...
    }
```

So for example all over my code i use it like :

```
<?php _e('Settings', WPB_PREFIX);?>
```

So far everything is ok, but if i end using two plugins in the same project i have to check all my code and change "WPB_PREFIX" as is already defined. There is an easy way of doing this without going throw all the code?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you seek [`defined()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) function. No? `$x = defined('WPB_PREFIX') ? WPB_PREFIX : 'default';`

Comment: In addition to my answer below, I *strongly* urge you to conform to the standard PHP code style, which is non-indented curly braces. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could (and should!) define them as [class properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) instead of global constants. You can have a base class which sets the defaults for the constants you need access to, and then extend the class:

```
class WP_Plugin_Base
{
    protected $wpbPrefix = 'wsm';
    protected $wpbSlug = 'wp-simple-monitor';
    // etc.
}

class WP_Plugin_Specific extends WP_Plugin_Base
{
    protected $wpbSlug = 'wp-plugin-specific';

    function someMethod() {
        _e('Settings', self::wpbPrefix);
        _e('Slug', self::wpbSlug);
    }
}
```

The output of the method in the latter class would be the original prefix, with the new slug. As [noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534127/naming-constants-on-a-boilerplate-class/16534240?noredirect=1#comment23762406_16534240), you'll need protected variables rather than class constants in order to be able to define things with concatenated pieces, e.g.:

```
protected $absPath = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . $wpbSlug;
protected $relPath = dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );
protected $pluginUrl = WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/' . $wpbSlug;
```

That way, whenever you use the specific class you need, you get all the benefits you're already getting from the generic class you have, but you don't have the intersection issue.

This also prevents you from trying to figure out what to *do* if it's already defined, and it also means that whenever it makes sense to leave the defaults in place, you can: `self::property` will retrieve the base class property if you haven't overridden it. That should get you everything you're looking for, and it won't clutter up the global namespace while you're at it.

Comment: Yeah, you probably right. This is most appropriate. Covers constant overwrite problem too.

Comment: But there is a problem, that `WBP_PREFIX` might be used regardless of any classes. `define('WBP_PREFIX', 'wsm'); class Settings{ const OWN_WBP_PREFIX = WBP_PREFIX; }`.

Comment: True, but if using classes sensibly, it shouldn't matter. You should do `classInstance->WPB_PREFIX`, *not* `WP_Plugin_Specific::WPB_PREFIX`. As long as you actually instantiate the class and refer to `self` internally and the instance externally, there's no problem.

Comment: or referes to [`static`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

Comment: Right; he should *definitely* avoid using this statically; that doesn't get you any benefits here.

Comment: This looks like the correct way, let me play tomorrow with it and then i will accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely. And playing with it yourself is definitely the right solution. Who knows? I might have made a syntax error! (On which note, if you find anything of that sort, please leave a comment so I can tweak the answer to fix it.)

Comment: this : const WPB_ABS_PATH = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/'. self::WPB_SLUG; won't work . Seems that i can not use variables or functions. const WPB_REL_PATH = dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ); won't work either

Comment: Im thinking that the proper way to do this what i want is just use private or protected variables. Do you agree?

Comment: Ah, yes, that's a good point; I'd missed that you were concatenating the pieces together. I'll update the answer to reflect that. And yes, `protected` is probably where I would go.